# Converting default format of created date yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in salesforce case Object

Tags: salesforce, apex

There is a createdDate field in Datetime standard Salesforce format for case I want to change it to dd-mm-tyyyy format actually I am showing list of case in flow for that I have created an apex class now it is default format that is yyyy-mm-dd so I need to change it dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the user’s locale to one that uses the desired date format. The Salesforce UI renders date time values in the time zone and locale format of the current user.

It’s generally not a good idea or a best practice to implement custom date rendering; there’s a wide variety of ways to get it wrong.